# How can I use Pywin32 inside venv?

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui, python-venv

There is a Python 3.7.2 installed. Inside venv doesn't work Win32gui.

When I use Python without venv:
python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import win32gui
> > >
> > > Without error.
> > >       When I use Python with venv:
> > >       (GameTest) D:\GameTest\Scripts>python
> > >       Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 23:09:28) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
> > >       Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> > >       import win32gui
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32gui'

How can I fix my problem?

Comment: Have you installed the pywin32 to the venv?

Comment: I solved the problem by simply resetting the environment